# Prezto Paradox theme not displaying properly

Tags: zsh

I have a question somewhat similar to: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236885/installing-powerline-fonts-for-zsh-prezto-theme

I'm on OSX 10.10.5 using Iterm2, Zsh, and Prezto with more or less vanilla configurations. I installed the powerline fonts as in the other question, and set both ANSI and non-ANSI font to be "Anonymous Pro for Powerline", and have set both anti-aliased to be true.

Here is what it looks like on my screen, which is quite far from the screenshot indicated in the source code. Now I'm stuck and can't find more relevant information via Google search. How do I fix this?

[image]

Here is what it should look like (taken from other question):

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are concerned about the colors, your setup is done correctly.

The default blue that zsh recognizes on OS X is the darker one from your screenshot.
What bugs me in your screenshot is that the last arrow is a bit higher.
You can try increasing the font spacing and see if that fixes the issue.
Also, to check if you properly installed the powerline fonts (which you probably did, looking from the screenshot) run this command:

```
echo "\ue0b0 \u00b1 \ue0a0 \u27a6 \u2718 \u26a1 \u2699"
```

Your output should be a 7 unicode characters: triangle, plus/minus sign, git branch, right arrow, x sign, thunder and a gear wheel.

I personally use the same zsh theme with the Hack font, and the dark blue color of the username annoyed me. To change the colors, you need to modify the theme file:

```
nano .zprezto/modules/prompt/functions/prompt_paradoxmod_setup
```

In the `prompt_paradox_build_prompt` function you can edit the following:

- line 48: at the end you have `%F{blue}%n%F{red}@%F{green}`. The `%F{color}` is a function provided by zsh which also accepts a number from 0-255
- line 49: the first argument of the `prompt_paradox_start_segment` function is the foreground color, again you can provide a number

I have the following mod of the theme:

- line 48: `%F{39}%n%F{green}@%F{yellow}`
- line 49: `prompt_paradox_start_segment cyan black`

Which produces the following output:

[image: Console theme]

As you can see my username is in light blue color, just the way I like it.

Since the function takes a number from 0-255 and not a hex code for the color, this table might come in handy: [xterm color chart](http://www.calmar.ws/vim/256-xterm-24bit-rgb-color-chart.html)

I hope this solves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the color issue, you can also change the colors theme used by your terminal - I use iterm2.  The default color theme causes the colors to display darker (see below screenshot):

[image: Default color theme]

When I switch to Solaris Dark, I get the colors that more closely match the screenshot on zpresto site:

[image: Solaris Dark]

Screenshots are of oh-my-zsh, but the same applies for zprezto.

By the way, you may want to take a look at ZIM too as an alternative: https://github.com/zimfw/zimfw